# Fit entire world (with correct zoom) to bounds in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using leafletJS to display a map (with 500px height and dynamic width). I'm using map.fitWorld(); and noWrap property to show the entire world map (without repetition).

is there a way to fill out the gray space (automatically) by zooming in just how much ever is required?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074862/ , probably.

Comment: @IvanSanchez a little shifted to the right https://postimg.cc/9RSj9dfx . Can i change something to fix that?

Comment: That's a different question. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks. will post a different question.